# Custom metadata with event request

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm firing off various events from my site to GA, and I want to be able to include arbitrary metadata with those requests so that i can retrieve the events later and group them by various categories. I unfortunately cannot fit this data into the Category/Action/Label setup they have currently.
I am, for example, passing in a `noninteractive` flag, and I was wondering if there is a way to send arbitrary flags in the same way as this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think custom dimensions and custom metrics are what you're looking for. If you're using the most recent version of GA (analytics.js), there's more info here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Assuming you want to count the number of instances of something (clicks on a button, let's say), you'd set the custom metric value to 1.

If you give more detail around what exactly you want to track and what shape you need the data in, I could give you more help.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Hey Tom. I'm looking to track impressions and clicks, and attach custom metadata to each impression/click so I can (for example) attach the ID of a banner to each request, and then use that data later to figure out which banner was clicked most

Comment: Gotcha - then I'd set a custom variable with the ID of the banner, and then two custom metrics - one that fires each time the banner is viewed, with a value of one (this will be impressions), and another that fires when the banner is clicked (also a value of one). This means you'll need to call the ga track function twice.

Comment: But then GA won't see these new variables as "events", yeah?

Comment: Correct - there's no easy way to shoehorn this into the event tagging functionality (at least by passing a flag). You could dynamically set the event names, but counting them in the web UI would be problematic (unless you are paying for GA Premium and have access to the logs).

Comment: Cheers Tom! Appreciate the insight